# Problems with .net-core self contained publish

Tags: docker, .net-core, .net-standard-1.6

I`m trying to publish a self-contained app, made in .net-core, following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index.

The repository with the code is in https://github.com/fontanaricardo/httpecho

I execute the commands:

```
$dotnet build -r debian.8-x64
$dotnet publish -c Release -r debian.8-x64
$docker build -t httpecho .
```

Starting the container:

```
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 httpecho
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstracti
ons', version: '1.1.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'
```

I'm doing something wrong?

## Update

Open the file **httpecho.deps.json**, in **publish** folder, references the folder that not exists.

```
"runtime": {
      "lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll": {}
    }
```

Comment: The first error says `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` and second says `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery`. Which is it?

Comment: @natemcmaster removed the Update 2, because it causing confusion.

Comment: Same error for `ubuntu.16.04-x64` and `netcoreapp1.0` framework.

Answer (score 4):

Your device have problem with proper distibute packages into your self contained publish (tried on my worked well). Try to fix packages by `dotnet restore`

Is there `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` in `debian.8-x64\publish`? If not try to add manually (and all other missing *.dll's) and then  try to run. If it will run without errors will be problem with proper distibute packages

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` is in the folder. I try to execute publish from the docker image `microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-sdk-projectjson,` but the error persist. the file `httpecho.deps.json` reference the `lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll`.